# Unity3D - 'SocialPlatforms' package is changed from 2018.1 to 2018.2?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

When i create games in Unity 2018.1 (maybe 2018.1.7) Environment.

After Unity update '2018.2', I try update my Unity version.

After updating, I just modified tiny path. not touch scripts, etc. I just changed images.

But, game is abnormal termination. I want to find cause.

And maybe I found.

but...

```
void Login()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool Success) => { // handle success or failure 
        if (true == Success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Login Success");
        }
        else { //Debug.Log("Login Fail");
            ; }
    });
}
```

It code is called just One time at 'Game Play Life Cycle Time'.

I use 'Google Play Games' plugin. so, After called 'Login()' method.

-> Call 'PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();' at some path.

But Calling *.Activate() method, game is shutdown, not calling any error message at logcat.

I trying to find error's cause. soon, i maybe found.

'Login()' method are abnormal working.

Why i guess 'Login()' method are error's cause?

because

'Calling "Login Success" but not Logging Google play service.'

...I really don't understand. i trying re-install GPG plugin, re-setting 'Google play - android setting', and re-setting oAuth setting.

But still not working : <

I really not understand that errors.

- Summary

  1. I updated Unity version 2018.1 to 2018.2
  2. Not touched codes, but when changed auto re-version project. game is abnormal working.
  3. I guess my 'Login()' method part are error's cause.
     3-1. because i checked logcat, call 'Login Success' but actually not login.
  4. So. i guess, 'Is changed Unity's Social Class?', So I wrote like a title.
  5. I already checked 'Google's oAuth service', 'GPG setting'.

[image: It log are 'Normal Working']
* It log are 'Normal Working'
(breaked message are just Encoding issue. not error : ] )

[image: It log are 'Abnormal Working']
* It log are 'Abnormal Working'

Comment: 1) Why Abnormal Logcat image have not 'Login Success' message? : because not printing at testing capture that image. : <
2) Why you have 'Normal working' logcat? : hey i also have backup apk.

Answer (score 1):

I found error's cause and solution.

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2013

damm'it.